# Modify edit box data display type error message

Tags: xpages

I have a edit box in my xpage and i've set data display type to number. I also have a error message component so I can display the error which i get if i insert any other char that is not a number. I get this message:

> This field is not a valid integer

So my question is- is there a way to modify this message so I can display whatever I want to in the message? Or I shouldn't bother with this and just achieve the functionality in other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is handled by the in-built number converter, so you would need to add your own converter to change the message and handle the conversion between the number required by the business logic and the string required for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DojoNumberTextBox and that will only allow number values.

Howard